# Переход с vue2 на vue3

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет. Работал с vue2 через cdn.

Есть 2 компонента и просто файл `index.html`

```
cars.js
motorcycles.js
index.html
```

`cars.js` содержит:

```
const cars={
     
    template:"<div>Тут машины</div>",
};
const app=Vue.createApp();
app.component('cars', cars));  
app.mount('#my');
```

`index.html` содержит:

```
<script type="module" src="cars.js"></script>

<div id="my"><cars></cars></div>
```

На данном этапе всё хорошо. Отображается "Тут машины".

Теперь мне нужно импортировать второй компонент в первый и там его использовать. Вот что я делаю.

Редактирую `cars.js:`

```
const cars={
     
    template:"<div>Тут машины</div><motorcycles></motorcycles>",
};
const app=Vue.createApp();
app.component('cars', cars));  
app.component('motorcycles', () => import('/motorcycles.js')); 
app.mount('#my');
```

Не работает. Моя проблема в том, что незнаю как правильно импортировать второй компонент. Или как объявить о втором компоненте.

Сейчас там так:

```
motorcycles.js содержит:
const motorcycles={
     
    template:"<div>Тут Мотоциклы</div>",
}; 
app.component('motorcycles', motorcycles));
```

Была идея сделать `export default motorcycles;` Но не помогло. Так же не помогло и createApp если прописать в компоненте motorcycles.js.
Во второй версии Vue я бы сделал так:  `Vue.component('motorcycles', motorcycles));`    и всё. И это работало бы. А как сделать на Vue3 это правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А документацию читал? А именно раздел `Quick Start :: Without Build Tools`

- https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools

**Добавлено для поддержки комментария**

Если тебя интересует именно асинхронная версия загрузки компонента, то это выглядит вот так. 2й параметр может быть Promise'ом.

```
Vue.component('motorcycles',  async () => {
   const request = await fetch("/js/motorcycles.js");
   return await request.text();
});
```

Comment: Читал. И после этого начал переходить на vue 3. Но отличий не вижу. Вьюху подключил. Компоненты тоже. Но не работает система

Comment: Я щас сделал так: 
    
   
const cars={ 
    template:"<div>Тут машины</div><motorcycles></motorcycles>",
}; 
    
import motorcycles from 'motorcycles.js'
    
   
const app=Vue.createApp();
app.component('cars', cars));  
app.component('motorcycles', motorcycles); 
app.mount('#my'); 
    
   
motorcycles.js содержит:
export default{
     
    template:"<div>Тут Мотоциклы</div>",
};    Тогда да работает

Comment: А если мне нужно в будущем использовать компонент motorcycles.js в качестве главного? Типо в index.html подключить просто файл motorcycles.js и вставить тег <motorcycles></motorcycles> это же ведь не сработает, выдаст ошибку, из-за того, что компонент не объявлен и нет createApp и.т.д. так как внем просто export default. Что тогда делать? В одном месте его нужно подключить в другой компонент а вдругом случае он сам является главным компонентом. Че делать?

Comment: const motorcycles={ 
    template:"<div>Тут мотоциклы</div>",
};
export default motorcycles;
const app=Vue.createApp();
app.component('motorcycles',motorcycles);
app.mount('#motorcycles');    Надеюсь такая запись решит сразу две мои проблемы)

Comment: Ты пойми что ты или собираешь компоненты на сервере и используешь компилятор в составе `@vue/cli`. Или работаешь с чисто клиентской частью, в таком случае подгрузка реализовывается на промисах. Есть ещё гибридная сборка, но там всё сложно. )))) Так на пальцах как это работает не пояснить.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, хоть я и читал доку несколько раз, и на разных форумах был. Но все же из-за твоей ссылки у меня появилась мысль попробовать такой вариант и он полностью решает мою проблему)    Вот он      const motorcycles={ template:"<div>Тут мотоциклы</div>", }; export default motorcycles; const app=Vue.createApp(); app.component('motorcycles',motorcycles); app.mount('#motorcycles');   то есть это и экспортировать и объявить о компоненте в одном файле.